# ternary condition in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ternary-operator

I have to implement the remember me functionality, so I have to pass the value for `$remember` as a second argument in the `Auth:attempt();` function. But the problem is when I am using this syntax for setting value in `$remember`, it displays syntax error

```
$remember = isset($request->input('remember')) ? true : false;
----------------------------------------------^//Expected: variable
```

But when I am using this syntax, it will not give any error

```
$remember = isset($request->remember) ? true : false;
```

Comment: What's the point of `?true:false`? `isset` itself already return a boolean

Comment: yeah, that i know, i am just asking about why it give syntax error

Comment: if i used like this `$remember=isset($request->input('remember'));`, it will also give the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`has` is used like this :

```
$remember = $request->has('remember'); //return true if the remember is selected :)
```

For your question what is the difference between above two syntaxes :

It's because `isset` is a language construct and not a real function. It is mentioned in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> **Warning**
>
> isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result
>   in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input):

```
$request->has('remember')
```

> You should use the `has` method to determine if a value is present on the request. The has method returns true if the value is present and is not an empty string.

Comment: used like this `$remember=isset($request->has('remember'))?true:false;`, having same error

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR you don't need to use `isset()` or ternary operator here since `has()` returns true or false. Do this `$remember = $request->has('remember');`

Comment: ok, it's working fine, but my question is same, what is the difference between above two syntaxes

Comment: got that `isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.`

Answer (score 2):

Request class already has a built-in method to check if a parameter is set:

```
if ($request->has('remember')) {
    // remember is set
} else {
    // remember is not set
}
```

But there is a better way to do what you are trying to achieve. request class also has a method `get`, it accepts the key as a first argument and the default value as the second (which is returned in case the key is not set)

So you can just write it like this:

```
Auth::attempt([...], $request->get('remember', false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$r = $request->input('remember');
$remember = isset($r)?true:false;
```